# ParseException while parsing string to date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

I want to parse string format "9/7/2016 07:40 p.m." into date. But I am getting parse exception. I tried using two three formats. But still getting the Exception.

I want to compare this parsed date with current date.

```
     SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",Locale.ENGLISH);

                    String upcomingEventDateTime = eventDate + " " + eventTime;

                    eventDateTime = df.parse(upcomingEventDateTime);

                    int compare = now.compareTo(eventDateTime);

                    if (compare == 1) {

                        upComingTasks++;
                    }
```

Which format I should use to parse this string? Thank you..

Comment: and what is "the Exception" ?

Comment: unparsble date at offset 0. @Stultuske

Comment: since we have no possible way of knowing what eventDate and eventTime are, what exactly do you expect us to do?

Comment: @Stultuske The question says quite clearly what string the OP is trying to parse.

Comment: @user6265109 The Javadoc for SimpleDateFormat lists all the formatting symbols.  You just need to pick the ones that match what you've got in your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [`SimpleDateFormat` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the format specification, yours is completely wrong.

Here's a working one:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy hh:mm a",Locale.ENGLISH).parse("9/7/2016 07:40 pm")
```

With slight change, "p.m." is not recognized by `SimpleDateFormat`, so you have to use PM/AM (without dots).

Comment: I have used this to get the time. No idea why p.m is with dots.         SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Date date = mCalendar.getTime();

        String time = df.format(date); @krzyk

Comment: @DavidWallace It parses the date, the only unknown is where is the month, is it July (7) or September(9).

Comment: @user6265109 So you have the time and format it into a string and later on you want to change it the other way around? Why? Can't you use the original date and time?